# How to get a Windows 10 complete memory dump on demand?

Tags: encryption, operating-systems, memory, ransomware

I was wondering what to do if by any chance I got infected with a Ransomware that could trick my AV suite, and my conclusion is that a complete memory dump would be the best option, as probably the encryption key would be there somewhere.

Searching online only showed me how to get the memory dumped on error, BSOD and the like, but not on demand. Some tutorials from many AV vendors even include a Restart step, which obviously is not something I would do during a Ransomware attack as I might lose the key for good.

So how could I dump all the system's memory in order to have a chance to find a encryption key there and possibly recover my files?

Comment: Encryption keys aren't 2 ways if the ransomware is good. You will not find the private key, you will only find the public key. THIS DOESN'T MEAN YOU SHOULD TRY. However, to answer your question there are a ton of tools to do this. f-response and encase to name a few. Not sure they will pull from a BSOD. It appears windows creates a minidump file. I'd research that.

Answer (score 2):

> So how could I dump all the system's memory in order to have a chance to find a encryption key there and possibly recover my files?

Don't count on that. I've seem lots of ransonmware analysis and a good amount of them create a private key, send it to the operators, and zero it afterwards. After that the encryption starts.

The key resides on memory for a very short time. If it was possible to detect the ransomware generating the key, it would be possible to just kill its process and nothing would be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, Microsoft bundled quite [a large collection of tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/), some more powerful than anything available for Windows.

I'm able to log activity going on in the background that I've never been able to see up until that point. At any rate, if they haven't created icons for *everything* - which they shouldn't, find ALL the EXE files that lack any kind of icon - they're command line only, no GUI. Either cut and paste or create a copy of them and stick them in your `C:\Windows\System32`

For your *immediate* purposes, just find `livekd64` (assuming your system is 64 bit? if not, use the plain `livekd`) and put it in `System32. It might help you acquire the dump information you're after.

Comment: This is my ignorance, lack of patience... and, more specifically, lack of attention to detail. I _just_ skimmed across and read the actual **reason** you want a dump file of your RAM. I suppose I _could_ be wrong, but I'd almost wager MY $1,500 computer _against_ the possibility of obtaining an encryption key.

Comment: Again, though... I _could_ be wrong. Are you referring to regular Windows OS capability to encrypt files via the properties dialog window? Or... a much more hopeless attempt - trying to dig up BitLocker encryption key? Since BitLocker gives you about 3 different ways to recover its key, I'm pretty much 100% certain you're talking about the Encryption option found under the Advanced button in each file's Properties tab.

Comment: Well, how come the encryption key won't be in memory? If the program is running, then the data is on RAM, the only alternative is if it uses asymmetric encryption, but since it's a lot slower I think many won't use.

Comment: No no no, I am talking about Ransonware encripting all my files, so they can ask for money later.

Comment: But @mFeinstein ... that's not what I meant. You're absolutely right - it would have to either be in random access memory OR... possibly the page file. How much virtual memory is your system allocating? No... my doubtfulness was due to believing the encryption key ITSELF would have to be encoded, encrypted... protected in SOME way.

Comment: Usually you store secrets in an encrypted form... But when you use them, they are exposed in memory, there's no way to use an encryption key in a program if it's not on its original form. The only way is to use a dedicated hardware that does the encryption for you and stores the key safely, like SIM cards do.

Comment: More than likely you have a system managed page file... which is just hard drive space allocated for use as virtual memory. Should it really be in raw form like you say, its far more likely to be somewhere in the pagefile than your random access memory.